# Use Java variable in HTML tag

Tags: java, html

I'd like to be able to use a java variable as one of the attributes of my HTML tag. For example, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
<% String questionId = "question" %>
Question: <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name=questionId><%=question %></textarea>
```

Where the name attribute would equal "question". The above doesnt work; is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I was a little unclear in my original post -- i just edited it. That is what I currently have and it does not work

Comment: I believe this would work if your file was a .jsp

Comment: Your variable is the problem. Please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35919004/5678086

Comment: Surely there are two ways (1) Java Server Pages, (2) Servelets

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the variable you set. Means you set `questionId` and accessing `question` It has to be fixed as below

```
<% String questionId = "question" %>
Question: <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name=questionId><%=questionId %></textarea> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

you've forgot the semicolon. try this it must work :

```
<% String questionId = "question"; %>
Question: <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name=questionId><%=question %> </textarea> <br>
```